# How to have a Optional type in an entity springboot

Tags: spring, spring-boot, hibernate, jpa

```
package com.example.Assessment.models;


import jakarta.persistence.*;
import lombok.*;
import java.util.Date;
import java.util.Optional;

@Builder
@AllArgsConstructor
@NoArgsConstructor
@Getter
@Setter
@ToString
@Entity
@Table(name = "assessment")
public class Assessment {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Integer id;

    @Column(name = "creator_user_id")
    private Optional<Integer> creatorUserId;

    @Column(name = "name", nullable = false)
    private String name;

    @SuppressWarnings("JpaAttributeTypeInspection")
    @Column(name = "categories", nullable = false, columnDefinition = "_varchar")
    private String[] categories;

    @Column(name = "expiry_time", nullable = false)
    private Date expiryDate;

    @Column(name = "max_applicants", nullable = false)
    private Integer maxApplicants;

    @Column(name = "start_date")
    private Date startDate;

    private Integer duration;

    @Column(name = "assessment_details")
    private String assessmentDetails;
}
```

I have a Dto coming from the controller where a single field creatorUserId is optional in it. now I was converting the dto to Assessment class. because creatorUserId is optional in dto I made it optional in Entity class Assessment. when I run it I am getting an error.

```
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'entityManagerFactory' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/orm/jpa/HibernateJpaConfiguration.class]: Could not determine recommended JdbcType for `java.util.Optional<java.lang.Integer>`
```

Comment: What sense does it make to have an Optional the column has nullable = false

Comment: My mistake, I didn't see it I have edited the code now. even then I am getting same error.

Answer (score 0):

See [How to use Java 8’s Optional with Hibernate](https://thorben-janssen.com/use-java-8-optional-hibernate/):

- use nullable type without Optional on the field
- add getter and setter operating on Optional

```java
@Column(name = "creator_user_id")
private Integer creatorUserId;

public Optional<Integer> getCreatorUserId() {
    return Optional.ofNullable(creatorUserId);
}

public void setCreatorUserId(Optional<Integer> creatorUserIdOpt) {
    this.creatorUserId = creatorUserIdOpt.orElse(null);
}
```